# How to create Soap based Web Service using Ecllipse and Tomcat 6.0?

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap

How to create Soap based  Web Service using Ecllipse galilio and Tomcat 6.0

Comment: just why... google can easily answer that question

Comment: I m able to create service and client but dont know what is soap call and made service is using soap or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally people on SO expect you to do some Googling, and to post specific questions once you run into specific problems with the tutorials that you find.

SOAP is XML with a specific set of elements: http://webdesign.about.com/od/soap/a/what-is-xml-soap.htm

Try to create web services without using Eclipse's tools: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Try to create web services with Eclipse's tools: http://javapapers.com/web-service/java-web-service-using-eclipse/

After you read and try these examples, come back and ask specific questions about what is tripping you up.